# What might be alternatives to Userena in Django?

Tags: django

I am interested if there are alternatives to Userena in Django. I want my website to have kind of serious feeling that a validation email be sent after registration, and able to change password, etc. Just curious what plugins are off the shelf.

Comment: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the website, I didn't know it before, but it is indeed useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has always been my go-to package for two step registration (validation email):
https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Django auth system already provides the change password functionality:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not sure you have any example sites running django-registration? I want to check what could be the final effect.

Comment: Just try it out. You can customise all the view and email templates anyway, but it provides the scaffolding you need